# Calculating the limit of a function?

Tags: limits

I've been trying to calculate the limit of the following, as $x$ tends to $0$:
$$f(x) = \left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^{1/x}$$

I've tried writing it as $e$ raised to the power of its log, but I am unable to solve it. Any tips on how to proceed will be appreciated!

Comment: Why am I unable to edit this?

Comment: Anyways, `$f(x) = \left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$` $f(x) = \left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: Sorry, I am new here and am still trying to figure out how everything works!

Comment: @KennyLau, you can't edit something if there's already an edit pending review.  If you're on a computer, hover your mouse over the grayed out edit button for an explanatory tooltip.

Comment: I see, thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 0}\left( \dfrac{e^x-1}x \right)^\frac1x=\lim_{x \to 0}\left( \dfrac{(1+x+\frac{x^2}2+o(x^2))-1}x \right)^\frac1x=\lim_{x \to 0}\left( {1+\frac{x}2+o(x)} \right)^\frac1x=\lim_{x \to 0}e^{\frac1x \ln\left( {1+\frac{x}2+o(x)} \right)}=\lim_{x \to 0}e^{\frac1x \left( {\frac{x}2+o(x)} \right)}=\sqrt e$

Answer (score 1):

A good trick for $1^\infty$ indeterminate forms that may be worth rembering is, if $\lim f(x) = 1$ and $\lim g(x) = \infty$ then

$$\lim f(x)^{g(x)} = \exp[\lim g(x)(f(x)-1)].$$

In this case

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^{1/x}=\exp\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\right).$$

Using L'Hospitals rule

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{2x}= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x}{2}= \frac1{2},$$

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{e^x-1}x\right)^{1/x}= e^{1/2}.$$

The proof of the trick rests on the well-known inequality $x/(1+x) \leqslant \ln(1+x) \leqslant x$ for $x > -1$.

Thus,

$$\frac{g(x)(f(x) - 1)}{f(x)} \leqslant g(x) \ln f(x) = g(x) \ln(1 + f(x) -1) \leqslant g(x)(f(x) - 1).$$

By the squeeze theorem

$$\lim g(x) \ln f(x) = \lim g(x)( f(x) -1).$$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Take log and use Lopitale rule.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I would do is take the logarithm of the whole thing:  If $y= \left(\frac{e^x- 1}{x}\right)^{1/x}$ then $ln(y)= (ln(e^x- 1)- ln(x))/x$.  Both of those go to negative infinity.  Which goes to negative infinity faster?

Comment: The power is not x, it is 1/x.